# Does vector::erase not work with reverse iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

The following code won't compile

```
some_vector.erase(some_vector.rbegin(), some_vector.rbegin()+1);
```

This is just an example, I know there's better option for deleting the last n elements.
GCC tells me that there is no matching function for erase. Did I do something wrong or does erase not work with reverse iterators ? It works fine with a forward iterator, though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not.  However, reverse iterators provide a `base()` method to obtain a forward iterator.  Take note that the returned forward iterator points to the element following the element the reverse iterator points to.

Or, to put it another way, `.rbegin().base() == .end()` and `.rend().base() == .begin()`

So the fixed code would look like this:

```
some_vector.erase(
    (++(some_vector.rbegin())).base(),
    some_vector.rbegin().base()
);
```

Note that we have to swap the order of the iterators around since they are reverse iterators; the second argument must be an iterator that *follows* the first iterator in the sequence, but without swapping the order of the reverse iterators this wouldn't be true.  So if we have two reverse iterators `a` and `b`, and `b >= a` then we can use this idiom for `erase()`:

```
container.erase(b.base(), a.base());
```

More generally, it holds for the range of reverse iterators [a, b) that the range [b.base(), a.base()) iterates the same sequence of elements in the opposite order.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unsuccessfully trying to debug my code since 1 week and I never assumed that the base() method was actually returning a off-by-1 iterator...

Comment: @AaaBbb [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) is an extremely valuable reference for reasoning about reverse iterators.